# captcha or recaptcha at Tank Auth

Tags: frameworks, recaptcha, tankauth

I was trying to make the Tank Auth to work on my web server and so far so good. The only problem I'm facing now is the captcha. it doesn't seem to work at the registration form. I mean I can't see the image at all. is there something I'm missing somewhere?? how about if I want to use the reCaptcha instead, how do I achieve that?

all comments are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer. There is a recaptcha settings in the file auth.php. just make it True and then add the private and public key to make it work. I hope it helps anyone looking for resolving the same issue.

Comment: its working for me, but not validating it. means i can register even if the words entered are not correct. Any help would be appreciated. thanks.